# NGINX Conf for wildcard certificate from comodo

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate

I'm trying to install a wildcard certificate bought from comodo.

I have my csr that starts with:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

which I don't seem to be using :/
and what I assume to be my private key which starts with:

```
 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I received 4 files from COMODO:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt 

COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt 

COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt 

STAR_my_domain.crt
```

I tried to

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt STAR_my_domain.crt > bundle.crt
```

I then edited my nginx config to the effect of :

```
ssl_certificate /certs/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /certs/private.key;
```

yet i get :

failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)

where did i go wrong?

Comment: And note that the order of the files in the bundle is important. The leaf certificate must be the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that answer out. I've been reading a LOT of SO answers for the past hours and couldn't find this one. And It was the exact fix I needed. *bows*